# How to export a specific number of rows to text files in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to export every 7 rows in a column to multiple text files inside a Google drive folder.

I have figured out how to export single rows into text files, but not multiple rows into one text file.

I have this which successfully exports one row to one text file:

```
function saveToTextfile() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
  var rows = range.getValues();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("folderName").next();
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext()) files.next().setTrashed(true);
  rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
    folder.createFile("row" + index + ".txt", row.join(", "));
  });
}
```

How can I change one row to one text file to seven rows to one text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to create the values from a sheet in the Spreadsheet as the text files.
- You want to create the text files every 7 rows.

  - You want to create the text files in the specific folder of your Google Drive.
  - For example, if the number of rows is 20, 3 text files are created.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
  folder.createFile("row" + index + ".txt", row.join(", "));
});
```

To:

```
var limit = 7; // In your case, the rows are used every 7 rows.
var split = Math.ceil(rows.length / limit);
for (var i = 0; i < split; i++) {
  var data = rows.splice(0, limit);
  var str = data.map(function(e) {return e.join(", ")}).join("\n");
  var filename = "row" + (i * limit + 1) + "-" + (data.length == limit ? (i + 1) * limit : (i + 1) * limit - (limit - data.length)) + ".txt";
  folder.createFile(filename, str, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
}
```

- In this modified script, when the number of rows is 20, 3 text files of `row1-7.txt`, `row8-14.txt` and `row15-20.txt` are created.
- In each text file, each row is splitted by `\n`.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [createFile()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfilename-content-mimetype)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: You understood it perfectly the modification works just fine thank you Tanaike!

Comment: @Conserta Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.